# In a TypeScript program should the global variables document and window be declared?

Tags: typescript

In one of my first attempts in TypeScript programming I have been using the global variables document and window without declaring their types. Is there a recommended practice on this?  For instance, is it advisable to declare something like:

var document : Document;
var window : Window;

Comment: document and window are already defined in lib.d.ts.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a recommended practice on this? For instance, is it advisable to declare something like:
> `var document : Document; var window : Window;`

NO. They are included in your compiliation context by the compiler using a file called `lib.d.ts`.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html